# Can't get navbar collapse to push my main content down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am taking a course in web development and I've gotten stuck, I know it has something to do with the containers and flexing but I cannot for the life of me figure it out, I've seen multiple examples and they are all similar to my HTML, CSS.
Here is [my github](https://github.com/luizpasqualetto/fullStackCourseWork/tree/main/Module3_solution) with all, the necessary files (only index.html and styles.css have been edited so focus on those). Here is the [github hosted page](https://luizpasqualetto.github.io/fullStackCourseWork/Module3_solution/).

[image: Picture of the issue]

Edit : Snippet

```css
body {
    color: #515a69;
    background-color: #b0b7c2;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* Header */
#header-nav {
  background-color: #d3dceb;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  height: 70px;
}

#header-nav .container { /* Fixes margins to match professors examples */
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#nav-list {
background-color: #515a69;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav-list a{
background-color: #515a69;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 0px;
}

#collapsable-nav {
    border: 0;
}

li{
 background-color: #515a69;
 border: 2px black;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 }

.navbar-brand h1 { /* Restaurant name */
  color: #515a69;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.navbar-brand a:hover, .navbar-brand a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}                            

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle, .navbar-header .icon-bar {
  border: 1px solid #61122f;
}

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -45px;
}

/* Main Content */

#maincontent div{
 background-color: #7e588d;
 border: 2px solid black;
 height: 1000px;
 overflow: auto;
}

div .container {
 width: 90%;
}

.row {
 color: #d3dceb;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
}

p {
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 overflow: auto;
}

#our-menu a, #our-menu a-hover{
    text-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#sushi h3, #beef h3, #chicken h3{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Food, LLC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  </head>
<body>

  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar static-top navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <div class="navbar-brand pull-left">
            <a href="index.html"><h1>Food, LLC</h1></a>
          </div>

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

          <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse-in navbar-collapse">
            <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-rights">
              <li class="visible-xs">
                <br><a href="#chicken">Chicken</a>
              </li>
              <li class="visible-xs">
                <br><a href="#beef">Beef</a>
              </li>
              <li class="visible-xs">
                <br><a href="#sushi">Sushi</a>
              </li>
            </ul><!-- #nav-list -->
          </div><!-- .collapse .navbar-collapse -->
          </div>
        </div> <!-- Navbar Header -->
      </div> <!-- Container -->
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section id="our-menu">
  <h1 class="text-center">Our Menu</h1>
  </section> 
  <div class="row">
    <div id="maincontent" class="container">
        <div id="chicken-container" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <section id="chicken">
            <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
             <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ac nunc vitae metus hendrerit convallis. Vestibulum nulla eros, molestie non feugiat ornare, rhoncus ac eros. Praesent maximus risus sed purus vestibulum porttitor. Nam risus ipsum, tristique et porta vitae, fermentum non elit. Vivamus sollicitudin sem sit amet turpis ornare, sed imperdiet magna pretium. Nullam eu ultricies orci, non aliquet nibh. Donec a auctor metus. Phasellus eu tellus tellus. Sed mi odio, pellentesque in velit in, tempor vestibulum massa. Sed nulla justo, interdum nec tincidunt nec, tincidunt non libero. Aliquam sapien arcu, blandit vel porta quis, porta vel ante. In sollicitudin tortor lobortis vestibulum blandit. Aenean velit neque, consequat eget mauris ac, consequat facilisis lectus. Sed pulvinar, orci sed commodo facilisis, erat diam facilisis magna, vitae luctus metus eros a magna. Fusce hendrerit vitae nisi facilisis viverra. Cras suscipit purus ut turpis tempor, non iaculis mauris imperdiet.

                 Nunc elementum lobortis lectus non dapibus. Sed augue nunc, semper vel ipsum nec, fermentum interdum metus. Proin et elementum nisi, nec fermentum velit. Aliquam congue efficitur diam id vestibulum. Aliquam ac tortor auctor, convallis ligula at, suscipit elit. Ut congue, turpis in elementum tincidunt, mauris odio imperdiet diam, vitae porta lectus lacus eu dolor. Vivamus tellus nunc, molestie quis iaculis nec, volutpat ut mi. Aenean mattis magna sit amet diam convallis, id consectetur risus placerat. Suspendisse et ex id dui porta vestibulum ac ut felis. Integer tristique, sapien a ultricies laoreet, nibh nisl sagittis augue, tincidunt faucibus libero dui vitae ante. Proin rutrum nulla sed ultricies fringilla. Fusce vel rutrum enim, suscipit porttitor nisl.

                 Sed pharetra egestas orci in rhoncus. Donec eros libero, euismod pretium varius sodales, pellentesque vel mi. Donec semper consectetur vulputate. In dapibus placerat est fermentum posuere. Donec mi felis, gravida in felis eu, sagittis consectetur nisi. Integer sollicitudin sagittis dui, eget ullamcorper erat euismod at. Proin tincidunt ullamcorper tortor, et vestibulum leo accumsan eget. Mauris porttitor, ante ut accumsan tincidunt, ex odio commodo arcu, sit amet lacinia ante risus ac mauris. Nunc blandit lorem cursus, euismod tellus eget, suscipit ligula.

                 Praesent imperdiet semper metus vel ultricies. Cras vel condimentum tellus. Vestibulum eget turpis nec nunc suscipit vestibulum ac vitae ligula. Curabitur bibendum varius rhoncus. Fusce mi ante, fringilla nec imperdiet non, feugiat bibendum dui. Donec eleifend, massa rhoncus luctus vehicula, felis ante dapibus dolor, nec imperdiet mi ipsum ut sem. Sed facilisis risus lectus, ut ultrices enim hendrerit id. Cras eget egestas erat. Duis feugiat at risus quis commodo. Fusce fermentum lacus at metus viverra, quis feugiat purus sagittis. Curabitur at sollicitudin felis. Duis venenatis leo ac felis bibendum porta.

                 Donec sodales varius dui eget pharetra. Vivamus ut ex porta, venenatis libero quis, pulvinar diam. Nunc quis dapibus velit, malesuada lacinia quam. Morbi in lacinia felis. Nullam euismod tellus diam, id condimentum nisi fringilla quis. In fringilla lectus quis laoreet fringilla. Praesent blandit, purus vel bibendum pellentesque, enim eros pellentesque quam, et ultrices eros erat ac mi. 
             </p>
             <a href="#our-menu" class="text-center"><h1>Return to the Top</h1></a>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div id="beef-container" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <section id="beef">
           <h3 class="text-center">Beef</h3>
             <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ac nunc vitae metus hendrerit convallis. Vestibulum nulla eros, molestie non feugiat ornare, rhoncus ac eros. Praesent maximus risus sed purus vestibulum porttitor. Nam risus ipsum, tristique et porta vitae, fermentum non elit. Vivamus sollicitudin sem sit amet turpis ornare, sed imperdiet magna pretium. Nullam eu ultricies orci, non aliquet nibh. Donec a auctor metus. Phasellus eu tellus tellus. Sed mi odio, pellentesque in velit in, tempor vestibulum massa. Sed nulla justo, interdum nec tincidunt nec, tincidunt non libero. Aliquam sapien arcu, blandit vel porta quis, porta vel ante. In sollicitudin tortor lobortis vestibulum blandit. Aenean velit neque, consequat eget mauris ac, consequat facilisis lectus. Sed pulvinar, orci sed commodo facilisis, erat diam facilisis magna, vitae luctus metus eros a magna. Fusce hendrerit vitae nisi facilisis viverra. Cras suscipit purus ut turpis tempor, non iaculis mauris imperdiet.

                 Nunc elementum lobortis lectus non dapibus. Sed augue nunc, semper vel ipsum nec, fermentum interdum metus. Proin et elementum nisi, nec fermentum velit. Aliquam congue efficitur diam id vestibulum. Aliquam ac tortor auctor, convallis ligula at, suscipit elit. Ut congue, turpis in elementum tincidunt, mauris odio imperdiet diam, vitae porta lectus lacus eu dolor. Vivamus tellus nunc, molestie quis iaculis nec, volutpat ut mi. Aenean mattis magna sit amet diam convallis, id consectetur risus placerat. Suspendisse et ex id dui porta vestibulum ac ut felis. Integer tristique, sapien a ultricies laoreet, nibh nisl sagittis augue, tincidunt faucibus libero dui vitae ante. Proin rutrum nulla sed ultricies fringilla. Fusce vel rutrum enim, suscipit porttitor nisl.

                 Sed pharetra egestas orci in rhoncus. Donec eros libero, euismod pretium varius sodales, pellentesque vel mi. Donec semper consectetur vulputate. In dapibus placerat est fermentum posuere. Donec mi felis, gravida in felis eu, sagittis consectetur nisi. Integer sollicitudin sagittis dui, eget ullamcorper erat euismod at. Proin tincidunt ullamcorper tortor, et vestibulum leo accumsan eget. Mauris porttitor, ante ut accumsan tincidunt, ex odio commodo arcu, sit amet lacinia ante risus ac mauris. Nunc blandit lorem cursus, euismod tellus eget, suscipit ligula.

                 Praesent imperdiet semper metus vel ultricies. Cras vel condimentum tellus. Vestibulum eget turpis nec nunc suscipit vestibulum ac vitae ligula. Curabitur bibendum varius rhoncus. Fusce mi ante, fringilla nec imperdiet non, feugiat bibendum dui. Donec eleifend, massa rhoncus luctus vehicula, felis ante dapibus dolor, nec imperdiet mi ipsum ut sem. Sed facilisis risus lectus, ut ultrices enim hendrerit id. Cras eget egestas erat. Duis feugiat at risus quis commodo. Fusce fermentum lacus at metus viverra, quis feugiat purus sagittis. Curabitur at sollicitudin felis. Duis venenatis leo ac felis bibendum porta.

                 Donec sodales varius dui eget pharetra. Vivamus ut ex porta, venenatis libero quis, pulvinar diam. Nunc quis dapibus velit, malesuada lacinia quam. Morbi in lacinia felis. Nullam euismod tellus diam, id condimentum nisi fringilla quis. In fringilla lectus quis laoreet fringilla. Praesent blandit, purus vel bibendum pellentesque, enim eros pellentesque quam, et ultrices eros erat ac mi. 
             </p>
             <a href="#our-menu" class="text-center"><h1>Return to the Top</h1></a>
        </div>
      </section>

        <div id="sushi-container" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <section id="sushi">
           <h2 class="text-center">Sushi</h2>
             <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ac nunc vitae metus hendrerit convallis. Vestibulum nulla eros, molestie non feugiat ornare, rhoncus ac eros. Praesent maximus risus sed purus vestibulum porttitor. Nam risus ipsum, tristique et porta vitae, fermentum non elit. Vivamus sollicitudin sem sit amet turpis ornare, sed imperdiet magna pretium. Nullam eu ultricies orci, non aliquet nibh. Donec a auctor metus. Phasellus eu tellus tellus. Sed mi odio, pellentesque in velit in, tempor vestibulum massa. Sed nulla justo, interdum nec tincidunt nec, tincidunt non libero. Aliquam sapien arcu, blandit vel porta quis, porta vel ante. In sollicitudin tortor lobortis vestibulum blandit. Aenean velit neque, consequat eget mauris ac, consequat facilisis lectus. Sed pulvinar, orci sed commodo facilisis, erat diam facilisis magna, vitae luctus metus eros a magna. Fusce hendrerit vitae nisi facilisis viverra. Cras suscipit purus ut turpis tempor, non iaculis mauris imperdiet.

                 Nunc elementum lobortis lectus non dapibus. Sed augue nunc, semper vel ipsum nec, fermentum interdum metus. Proin et elementum nisi, nec fermentum velit. Aliquam congue efficitur diam id vestibulum. Aliquam ac tortor auctor, convallis ligula at, suscipit elit. Ut congue, turpis in elementum tincidunt, mauris odio imperdiet diam, vitae porta lectus lacus eu dolor. Vivamus tellus nunc, molestie quis iaculis nec, volutpat ut mi. Aenean mattis magna sit amet diam convallis, id consectetur risus placerat. Suspendisse et ex id dui porta vestibulum ac ut felis. Integer tristique, sapien a ultricies laoreet, nibh nisl sagittis augue, tincidunt faucibus libero dui vitae ante. Proin rutrum nulla sed ultricies fringilla. Fusce vel rutrum enim, suscipit porttitor nisl.

                 Sed pharetra egestas orci in rhoncus. Donec eros libero, euismod pretium varius sodales, pellentesque vel mi. Donec semper consectetur vulputate. In dapibus placerat est fermentum posuere. Donec mi felis, gravida in felis eu, sagittis consectetur nisi. Integer sollicitudin sagittis dui, eget ullamcorper erat euismod at. Proin tincidunt ullamcorper tortor, et vestibulum leo accumsan eget. Mauris porttitor, ante ut accumsan tincidunt, ex odio commodo arcu, sit amet lacinia ante risus ac mauris. Nunc blandit lorem cursus, euismod tellus eget, suscipit ligula.

                 Praesent imperdiet semper metus vel ultricies. Cras vel condimentum tellus. Vestibulum eget turpis nec nunc suscipit vestibulum ac vitae ligula. Curabitur bibendum varius rhoncus. Fusce mi ante, fringilla nec imperdiet non, feugiat bibendum dui. Donec eleifend, massa rhoncus luctus vehicula, felis ante dapibus dolor, nec imperdiet mi ipsum ut sem. Sed facilisis risus lectus, ut ultrices enim hendrerit id. Cras eget egestas erat. Duis feugiat at risus quis commodo. Fusce fermentum lacus at metus viverra, quis feugiat purus sagittis. Curabitur at sollicitudin felis. Duis venenatis leo ac felis bibendum porta.

                 Donec sodales varius dui eget pharetra. Vivamus ut ex porta, venenatis libero quis, pulvinar diam. Nunc quis dapibus velit, malesuada lacinia quam. Morbi in lacinia felis. Nullam euismod tellus diam, id condimentum nisi fringilla quis. In fringilla lectus quis laoreet fringilla. Praesent blandit, purus vel bibendum pellentesque, enim eros pellentesque quam, et ultrices eros erat ac mi. 
             </p>
             <a href="#our-menu" class="text-center"><h1>Return to the Top</h1></a>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div><!-- Row -->
   </div><!-- Main Content -->

  <!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main content should be pushed down when the navbar is expanded, I also had to setup a z-index for the collapsible menu so it wouldn't be overlapped by the main-content (which is probably doing something funky to it too) so I know there is something wrong in my navbar / header, the body is working perfectly as intended.

I am using an older version of bootstrap because that is what the professor who is teaching my course is using, if you believe a newer version of bootstrap will work I can for sure change everything up, I've just spent the last 10 hours doing this, setting up the page took me 50 minutes so I'm kind of at the end of my rope, if this doesn't work I'm just going to restart from scratch.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Front-end protip: Never dump URLs in your page (or post). Create proper links.

Comment: I created a snippet and added it to the my question, thank you again Isherwood for the advice, I've only ever used stackoverflow for other types of programs and they never required a snippet so I had no idea that was even a function! I decided to keep the github page / directory links in case someone needs it to help me, I'm still actively trying to figure this out and if I can I will post a solution here in the comments and edit the original question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by removing the **height: 70px;** inside of my **#header-nav** ID styling, everything works perfectly now :)